# Calculate mean daily rainfall from hourly data with start and end that doesn't follow 0 - 24

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset with hourly rainfall (mm) and I wish to calculate mean daily rainfall. With 20.00 as start and endpoint, not 00.00 - 24.00. Will it be possible to get mean value (rainfall) from 20.00 to 20.00?

Here is the dataset with date, time and rainfall (mm).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JlEGTsJpAAVBQW2v6VTD3B-mrp9W6tWD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In the example data you shared, there is only "00:00" as time. How do you want to extract 20:00 from this data?

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong file. I will update it with the correct data asap.

Comment: @bird, I have updated the file now

Comment: Please don't upload data to external sites. See how to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on including data in the question itself. Ideally you'd also include the desired output for that sample input so that possible solutions can be tested and verifies. We don't need all your data, just enough to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(row_number() != 1:20) %>% 
  mutate(x_axis = trimws(`Date and time`, whitespace = ' .*')) %>% 
  group_by(group_id = cumsum(Hour == 20)) %>% 
  mutate(mean20_20 = mean(`Rainfall mm`)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x_axis, y=mean20_20, group=1)) +
  geom_point(size= 1, color = "blue")+
  geom_line(color = "red")+ 
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. I do get this error message: Warning message:
In row_number() != 1:20 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length, could I ingore this?

Comment: Would it be possible to get columns with sum, min and max also? Note: I added a new file with column names without space.